# Not able to click element ,further no error is displayed in protractor console

Tags: javascript, xpath, protractor

I have a button with a cross icon, which I am trying to click.Below is my protractor code:

```
browser.sleep(5000);
removepersona.isPresent().then(function(displayed){
if(displayed){
removepersonaval.click();
```

where xpath for elements are:

```
button: var removepersona= element(by.css('ul[class="tags"] li'));
cross icon: var removepersonaval= element(by.css('ul[class="tags"] li 
span'));
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<ul _ngcontent-c5="" class="tags">
<!----><li _ngcontent-c5="">BIKER&nbsp;
<span _ngcontent-c5="">×</span>
</li>
`enter code here`</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Locators looks fine.

Do a console.log and check if `displayed is true`.

```
removepersona.isPresent().then(function(displayed){
  if(displayed) {
  console.log("displayed"); 
     removepersonaval.click();
  }else{
     console.log("Not displayed"); 
  }  
})
```

Comment: Tried this with wait condition to check until the element is clickable and then go with the click.

    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(removepersonaval, 
    8000)).then(function(clickable){
    if(clickable){
    console.log("Displayed");
    removepersonaval.click();
    }
    else{
    console.log("Not displayed");
     }
     });

It shows status 'Displayed in the console but still does not click'

Answer (score 0):

I know what the problem is! Even though you can see the button, the actual clickable element is probably 0 px size, and protractor clicks only on visible elements with size greater than 0.

So you need to go with JS script. Define this action in your code

```
    /**
     *  Clicks on passed element by injecting js click() in the context of window
     *  @param {ElementFinder}      $element                        Locator of element
     *  @param {number}             [timeout=timeouts.ms1000]       Time in ms (med. is 1000ms)
     *  @return {promise.Promise}
     */
    jsClick: ($element, timeout = timeouts.ms1000) =>
        browser.wait(
            protractor.ExpectedConditions.presenceOf($element),
            timeout,
            "waitThenClickScript on " + $element.locator()
        ).then(() => browser.executeScript(
            "arguments[0].click();",
            $element.getWebElement()
        ))
```

It will wait for presence of the elem, and then inject code in browser console to click the elem. So just do

```
jsClick(removepersona);
```

It is also good to use when you don't want to know if something is visible and you want to click an element regardless (without scrolling down the page until it is visible). On the other hand, do not entirely rely on it, since protr click is a part of your UI verification